# Korean Traditional Clothes for each Dynasty

Tags: everyday-life, fashion, clothing

I searched everywhere but couldn't find a site that provide detailed clothes worn by the people of Korea in ancient time. I would like to search the changes in fashion and costume over time. Here are some examples that may be useful, but I'm really looking for a more detailed timeline:

- [Traditional Court Clothing](http://www.lifeinkorea.com/culture/cclothes/cclothes.cfm)
- [Clothes: period clothing](http://www.lifeinkorea.com/cgi-bin/pictures.cfm?FileName=court8)
- [The three kingdoms of Korea (video)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vre52B4Qskk)

Comment: I could object on the basis that this is a request for references, but this is a fascinating question. You can acquire these resources for European and American clothing styles. (I suspect that if I searched I could find "Fashion pictures for left handed cowboys with a lisp by decade in Wyoming".)  Is it really difficult to find these resources for Korea? Is it just Korea, or are other Oriental markets underserved?

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace: The only one I found is on the link above (which almost matches what I looking for). I would like to see more detailed timeline with the differences of the clothes being wear. I prefer Korea but I would be glad if there is another things like China. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible source is

[Traditional Korean Costume](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1905246048)

Given that the authors are listed by their affiliation with [Ewha's Women's University](http://www.ewha.ac.kr/mbs/ewhaen/), I'm willing to bet that they have additional academic papers availble, and are probably willing to correspond on the topic and suggest other resources. I searched for the first author's name on the Ewha University site and got back results, but was unable to translate the Korean, even with the assistance of Google.

[Cathy Raymond](https://plus.google.com/u/1/103483555539158593557/about) who is one of my go-to authorities on fashion disclaims any particular knowledge of Korean fashion, but recommended [Hanbok: The Art of Korean Clothing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1565910826) which is apparently out of print, but may be available from a library. She also drew my attention to [Chosun](http://english.chosun.com/site/data/html_dir/2006/05/29/2006052961020.html). She offered the following comment:

> Moreover, historical costume research isn't that systematized.  We have what we have on costume history in the West largely because we have had a lot of talented amateurs who've done and published research.  Costume and textile study is still a bit of a ghetto for historians and archaeologists though that's finally changing, thank heaven.

Both that second source and a third source recommended [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanbok) as a surprisingly good source.

Hope that is of some help.

Comment: Wow amazing, thank you very much for your detailed explanation and reference.. :)